# .NetStandard: Missing Type Methods and Properties

Tags: c#, standard-library

I have a code in PCL that I want to migrate to .NetStandard. Unfortunately tho, my code is dependent on .Net reflection and I cant find some of the methods previously available. 
So here is the list of methods or properties that I cant find under .NetStandard. Can any one point me in right direction about how to refactor my code?

```
Type.IsInstanceOfType()
Type.IsAssignableFrom()
Type.GetNestedTypes()
Type.GetConstructors()
Type.IsClass
Type.IsEnum
Type.IsValueType
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`GetTypeInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). Then those members are available off the TypeInfo now.

```
var example = typeof(string).GetTypeInfo().IsClass;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `ReflectionBridge` : https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReflectionBridge/